# Most common pattern to implement a settable module scoped variable

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, ecmascript-6, module

I am writing a client to talk to a server API in JavaScript. I have an OOP background but am trying to embrace modern EcmaScript.

So I started with this:

customerApi.js:

```
const baseUrl = "http://myapi";
export const getCustomers = () => { /* get customer code */ }
export const addCustomer = cust => {}
export const deleteCustomer = id => {}
```

All the functions use baseUrl.

Now I want to refactor so that the code that uses customerApi.js sets/passes in the baseUrl, and the only ways I have come up with are -

make it a class:

```
export default class customerApi {
  constructor(baseUrl) {
   this._baseUrl  baseUrl;
  }
}
```

Pass it into every method:

```
export const getCustomers = (baseUrl) => { /* get customer code */ }
export const addCustomer = (baseUrl,cust) => {}
export const deleteCustomer = (baseUrl,id) => {}
```

Wrap in a function:

```
const moduleFn = baseUrl => (
  return {
    getCustomers: () => { /* get customer code */ }
    addCustomer: (cust) => {}
    deleteCustomer: (id) => {}
  }
)
export default moduleFn;
```

These are just examples. 
What is the most common pattern to implement a "settable" variable on a module?

Comment: They all work fine, so I'm afraid what you're asking is opinion-based

Comment: reworded to make less opinion based, although I am ok with opinions.need a stackoverflow for design pattern opinions.

Comment: The `class` is the most common. The object factory is pretty much equivalent to the class. Individual functions are less common as it's a nuisance to pass the `baseUrl` everywhere.

Comment: Maybe this is the spot: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/389371/design-pattern-to-implement-a-settable-javascript-module-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the function approach

```
export default function(baseUrl){

  return Object.freeze({
    getCustomers: () => { /* get customer code */ }
    addCustomer: (cust) => {}
    deleteCustomer: (id) => {}
  })

}
```

This is because all the functions have closure on the baseUrl and no extra work is required.

Client code can simply

```
import yourmodule from 'yourmodule';
var derp = yourmodule('www.derp.com')
```

Comment: I do agree this has the best API for the client code, no instantiation, etc.